# Where to put member variables in my interface?

Tags: c++, class, interface, member

The c++ guidelines say not to put any data in the base class and also not to use trivial getter and setter methods, but rather just member variables, but where do I put the member variables in my data base access implementation? If I put it in one of the derived classes, I get the compiler error that my class db_interface does not have such a member.

```
#include <boost/core/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class db_interface : boost::noncopyable{
    
    public:
        void connect() const {connect_to_DB();}
        virtual ~db_interface(){};
    

    private:
        virtual void connect_to_DB() const = 0;
};



class postgreSQL : public db_interface{
    
    private:
        void connect_to_DB() const { std::cout << "THIS IS POSTGRESQL"<< std::endl;  }
        
    
};


class liteSQL : public db_interface{
    
    public: 
        std::string dbName;
    
    private:
        void connect_to_DB() const { std::cout << "THIS IS LIGHTSQL"<< std::endl; } 
    
};


class DBFactory {
public:
    virtual db_interface *createDB(std::string) = 0;
};

class Factory: public DBFactory {
public:
    db_interface *createDB(std::string type) {
        if(type == "LiteSQL") {
            return new liteSQL;
        }
        else if(type == "PostgreSQL") {
            return new postgreSQL;
        }
        return nullptr; 
    }
};
```

Comment: What does "c++ guidelines" mean? I'm unaware of the existence of any kind of Bureau Of C++ Guidelines, that issues directives on how C++ should or should not be used.

Comment: Interfaces have no members, only functions (like getters and setters). There is nothing wrong with getters and setters. Example you can make a getter that is guaranteed NOT to change the value of the underlying member (const getter). Which is much more maintainable design. So what guidelines do you use? Also try to use standard C++ as much as you can (boost is good, but I wouldn't add a dependency just for noncopyable)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-protected

Comment: Ok, it's a web site. Great. But it's still unclear what authority this web site has in issuing directives on how C++ should or should not be used.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Bjarne Stroustrup is the original author of that set of guidelines.  It is treated with some reverence within the C++ community.

Comment: Sure, but, again, I fail to see how that establishes any kind of an authority to dictate C++ design choices. These are, after all, the same rocket scientists that created `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @Namal - Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?  Your code compiles fine for me when removing the Postgres include (I don't have the dev package installed).

Comment: "It's a web site." It's the committee's web site. With guidelines written by the founder and some "very smart(TM)" people.  It's fine to drive home the point about the difference between guidelines and hard rules, but you're going about it all wrong.

Comment: OP, the linked guideline is specifically about `protected` data. The next guideline is specifically about the interface. Create your interface (with no data), inherit from your interface to create your base class (with private data), and then derive as needed.

Comment: I think you just overengineer/overcomplicating. simply put it where it belongs.

Comment: and remember c++ has strong static template, not every thing need to go though interface.

Comment: I agree with @appleapple. Do you really need, *at runtime*, the ability to switch between `liteSQL` and `postgreSQL`?

Comment: "The c++ guidelines say not to put any data in the base class" Where? They say to avoid `public` and `protected` data members in a class, but there's nothing wrong with `private` data in an abstract class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth pointing out the guidelines are just that. Some of them even contradict each other. It's up to you to be the engineer and decide what guidelines make sense for you and your project.

However, these guidelines do not really contradict each other.

The first one you linked to is: [**C.133: Avoid protected data**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c133-avoid-protected-data)

The other guideline linked in that one is: [**C.121: If a base class is used as an interface, make it a pure abstract class**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c121-if-a-base-class-is-used-as-an-interface-make-it-a-pure-abstract-class)

The other guideline linked is the one you seem to be skipping and subsequently tripping yourself over: [**C.9: Minimize exposure of members**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c9-minimize-exposure-of-members)

C.133 links to last one with the text **Prefer `private` data**.

The ideas being presented do not conflict, but they do take the separation of concerns to a level that is less common in C++ land.

Mainly, your interface should just be an interface. In that regard, putting data in your interface makes no sense.

You can then derive from that interface to create your 'base' class.  When here, don't make your data `protected`. Make it `private`. Your base class is then the *only* class responsible for that data. Protected functions like getters and setters do make sense here for your derived classes to make changes *which your base class alone is responsible for handling/validating*.

On top of that, I actually don't like the idea of the interface being all public pure virtual functions and instead I prefer NVI or Non-Virtual Interfaces. Here's a short example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Interface
class PetInterface {
 public:
  virtual ~PetInterface() = default;

  std::string speak() const { return speak_v(); }

  std::string name() const { return name_v(); }

 private:
  virtual std::string speak_v() const = 0;
  virtual std::string name_v() const = 0;
};

// Base class
class Pet : public PetInterface {
 public:
  Pet() = default;
  Pet(std::string name, std::string vocal) : m_name(name), m_vocal(vocal) {}

  virtual ~Pet() = default;

 private:
  std::string m_name;
  std::string m_vocal;

 protected:
  std::string name() const { return m_name; }

  std::string vocal() const { return m_vocal; }
};

class Dog final : public Pet {
 public:
  Dog() = default;
  Dog(std::string name) : Pet(name, "Woof") {}

 private:
  std::string speak_v() const override { return vocal(); }

  std::string name_v() const override { return name(); }
};

class Cat final : public Pet {
 public:
  Cat() = default;
  Cat(std::string name) : Pet(name, "Meow") {}

 private:
  std::string speak_v() const override { return vocal(); }

  std::string name_v() const override { return name(); }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PetInterface>> pets;

  pets.emplace_back(new Dog("Fido"));
  pets.emplace_back(new Cat("Dame Whiskers"));

  for (const auto& i : pets) {
    std::cout << i->name() << " says \"" << i->speak() << "\"\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
Fido says "Woof"
Dame Whiskers says "Meow"
```

`Pet` is still an abstract class, as only 'leaf' classes should be concrete.

One final note is that you don't need boost to make a thing non-copyable. Just `= delete` the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: `Pet` is only synthetically abstract, as both subclasses define `speak_v` and `name_v` the same way

Comment: Good point. I was trying to come up with relatively simple example that justify these guidelines, but I went a bit too simple.

Answer (score 2):

You should use use trivial getter and setter methods.  Pure virtual in the base class, and implemented in derived classes.

From [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#SS-aims):

> We do not suffer the delusion that every one of these rules can be effectively applied to every code base... Consider these rules ideals for new code, opportunities to exploit when working on older code, and try to approximate these ideals as closely as feasible.

You should not follow **[Avoid trivial getters and setters](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c131-avoid-trivial-getters-and-setters)** because you are implementing a **Database interface**, and the express purpose of a database is "setting" and "getting".

Comment: you're always setting and getting, it's just what computer does.